# How do I send multiple files when the server is requested using node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to anything web-development related (I've only been coding using luau for about a year now), and I'm having trouble sending multiple files when my server gets pinged, because I want to have a separate style.css file, as well as different script things.

I've left out MouseDraw.js and style.css, but when I added them directly into index.html they worked, and I can't see them when I inspect element on the website so I think it's just that they aren't being sent.

Is it possible to send them or do I have to just put them in every file?

I would post an image of how it's structured but I'm new so I can't, but it's all under a folder, and then there's just 'Server.js' and a folder called Client, which has everything I want to send to the client.

Server code:

```
const http = require('http');

const fs = require('fs').promises

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

let loadedPageInfo;

fs.readFile(__dirname + "/Client/index.html")  // Get and read the HTML data for this page
    .then((contents) => {
        loadedPageInfo = contents
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Could not load index.html ${error}`)
    })

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(loadedPageInfo || "Error loading");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Client:

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title>Drawing</title>
    <link rel = "stylsheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">

</head>

<body> 
    <h1>Heading One</h1>
    <p1>Message from my computer:</p1>

    <p2><samp><br><br>File not found.<br>Press F1 to do nothing</samp></p2>

</body>

<script> src = "MouseDraw.js" </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`style.css` will be requested as a new http request from the browser.  It will be asking for `/style.css`.  Your http server just sends `loadedPageInfo` no matter what the incoming request path is, so when the browser asks for `/style.css`, your http server just sends it `loadedPageInfo`.  The browser will probably see that it's an incorrect file type (e.g. not a CSS file) and will end up ignoring it.

Same thing would happen for `MouseDraw.js`.  If you want the browser to be able to get `/style.css` and `/MouseDraw.js`, then you will need to check for those in your  http server and send the right file that matches the request.

In the Express framework, you can configure `express.static()` to automatically serve a bunch of static HTML files like these, but without that, you have to literally write code for each separate http request that you want to serve, checking the incoming path of the request and sending the file that matches that request.

I'd really recommend using the very lightweight Express web server framework as it makes all of this simpler without getting in your way.  But here's the general idea for coding it manually:

```
function sendFile(res, file) {
    const filename = path.join(__dirname, "/Client", file);
    fs.readFile(filename).then(data => {
        res.end(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
    });
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    switch(req.url) {
        case "/":
            sendFile(res, "index.html");
            break;
        case "/style.css":
            sendFile(res, "style.css");
            break;
        case "/MouseDraw.js":
            sendFile(res, "MouseDraw.js");
            break;
        default:
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end();
            break;
    }
});
```